# Unity Raycast не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю механику брони на unity при помощи raycast. Вкратце - raycast  попадает на меш коллайдер, рассчитывается угол падения и из этого уже результат попадания. НО если добавить на объект rigidbody, то всё ломается... Меш коллайдер(дочерний объект объекта, на котором висит rigidbody) уже перевел в convex, также читал, что при использовании rigidbody для расчета попадания Raycast'а нужно использовать конструкцию RaycastHit.collider.transform, но она тоже не работает...

```
if (hit.transform.GetComponent<ArmorController>())
        {
            ac = hit.collider.transform.GetComponent<ArmorController>();
```

где ac - ArmorController(В нем кроме толщины брони и полученного урона в результате выстрела ничего нет).

Также пробовал hit.gameObject.transform.GetComponent,, но это ничего не изменило. Как тогда взаимодействовать с mesh collider, если есть rigidbody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, разобрался. В общем, надо не RaycastHit.gameObject.transform.GetComponent писать, а RaycastHit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent! Все оказалось просто) Пользуйтесь)